# eclipse 4.14.0 using var keyword in java, made changed to javaSE10 (jdk17), then error on building project

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var x = 1;
}
```

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2022-02-04 20:07:11.784
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 0

Comment: Show us the full log, not an incomplete fragment. Why are you using an Eclipse release which is 8 releases old, try the current Eclipse 4.22 (2021-12)

Comment: What greg-449 says. And Eclipse 4.14 was released long before Java 17, so it's strange where you get this _"(jdk17)"_ (probably just a label you named misleadingly).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.

JDK17 stands for jdk-17.0.1 (I think is the last version)

I installed the last Eclipse Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0)

Now the error was gone. I am a newbie in Java and also Eclipse, I just started to learn now.

I suppose that is a incompatibility JDK 17 and Eclipse 2019.
Now everything OK.
Thanks so much for the help.